# buffered writer VS memory Mapped IO for writing CSV file with lots of data

Tags: java, file, io

I have gone through the url in which it is preferred that for writing huge and bulk of data , use buffer writer but I just want to know its advantages over memory mapped io, since main focus was to make this process as faster as possible but in jdk 1.5 memmory mapped io was also faster so why it is not preferred

Answer (score 1):

I use memory mapped files in Chronicle however I would say

Memory mapped files are much harder to work with esp for text as you need random access and text has varying length characters.  Plain IO is the simplest usually much faster than your hardware so unless you have a PCI SSD card, you won't notice much difference for larger files.

In short, if your write speed is slow, check which hard drive you are writing to as there is not much you can do in software to make it faster. (Except use compression)

Answer (score 1):

Memory mapped I/O is:

1. 20% faster than java.io when reading
2. Unusable when writing files of unknown length, as you have specify the length when mapping.

Comment: so in terms of writing there is no competitor of buffered writer